# Verificar el tipo de usuario y redirigir a una vista

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

tengo un problema con mi condición if, necesito hacer que redirija a la ruta 'login' si el usuario loggeado no tiene rol tipo **escaner o administrador**.
el problema es que si el usuario es administrador lo manda al login.

```
  if (Auth::user()->tipo != 'escaner' || Auth::user()->tipo != 'administrador') {

        return redirect()->route("login");

        }
```

ayuda pls

Comment: tiene que ser !=  para que solo redirija a login a los usuarios que no sean tipo escaner o administrador.

Comment: gracias, ya corregí la sintaxis, pero la condicion solo se cumple cuando el rol es escaner,  si es administrador me manda al login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es que se redirija al usuario si se cumplen las dos condiciones (que no sea ni `escaner`, ni `administrador`), por lo que el operador debería ser `&&`, no `||`.

```
if (Auth::user() - > tipo != 'escaner' && Auth::user() - > tipo != 'administrador') {

  return redirect() - > route("login");

}
```

Ahora mismo, desde `administrador` te redirige porque se cumple una de las condiciones (no es `escaner`). Al usar el operador `||` le estás diciendo que redirija si se cumple una condición o la otra.

El operador `&&` exige que se cumplan las dos condiciones para redirigir, que es lo que creo que pretendes.

Answer (score -1):

cambia el ó por y.
|| => &&
en el operador.

Comment: Esta respuesta es correcta.. pero considera explicar mucho mejor la solucion.. mira por favor [answer]